# LibGDX actor registers mouse clicks in wrong places

Tags: libgdx, actor, stage, scene2d

I got a screen with a stage. I add UIGroup (which draws all the ui elements) and BattleSceneGroup (which draws all the actors needed for the battle) to the stage. Since I am using one stage for both of those groups, the y = 0 coordinate for my BattleSceneGroup starts at y = 230 , because UIGroup which is at the bottom of the screen, is 230px high.

Now, when I am drawing actors at their appropriate place (actual place, plus 230 for y-coordinate) their bounds seem to be set ~300px above them. Only when I click ~300px above the actors the clicks get registered.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I set my bounds on the actor as following:
actor.setBounds(actor.getX(), actor.getY(), actor.getWidth(), actor.getHeight());

Since the actor gets drawn in the correct place, I would assume that the bounds should be correct as well.

Comment: Probably would be much simpler to use two stages.

Comment: @JaroslavGorshkov It could help to make the bounds visible. You can do that by enabling the debuglines like so: stage.setDebugAll(True)
Or you can also enable it for an single actor.